# Why won't any other video file format work except .mov?

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I have an app on the app store which plays a selection of videos. Currently all of the videos are in the .mov file format but this makes the size of the app rather large so i'm trying to use a different file format to reduce the overall size of the app.
I am trying to use the mp4 format as this is reducing the size of each video by more than a half but when I do, the app crashes when I try to play the video with the following error message:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter
I have used the following code for each video in my implementation file and changed the file name and type to match the new video so I don't understand why there should be a problem with the file path.

```
- (IBAction)playDaresWins:(id)sender {
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"DaresWins" ofType:@"mov"]];
_moviePlayer =
[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
 initWithContentURL:url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:_moviePlayer];

_moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
_moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
[_moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`.mov` isn't a video format or codec, it's a container. The developer documentation provides a list of supported video codecs, bit rates, and resolution ([link here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html) - I won't post them here as they can change from OS version to OS version).

However, I don't think that's the problem, because it looks as if you're getting an exception when you're creating the `NSURL`, not when you're playing the video. That suggests that the path you're providing for your video doesn't exist. Are you sure you have a) the right filename, b) the right extension (perhaps it's MP4 instead of MOV), or c) have added the movie file into your project correctly?